# Include empty spaces when selecting from row in Open XML

Tags: vb.net, openxml

My Excel looks like this

```
 A    B    C    D
      1    2    3
```

I use this,

```
Dim row As DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row = sheetData.Descendants(Of DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row)().FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.RowIndex.Value = 1)
```

I only get 3 Cells (B,C,D) in my result. How do i include the blank spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Excel file contains only cells filled with their addresses. Empty cells are "virtual".

You can check by address cells, the "missing" cells are .
To translate the address (which is in "A1" style) to number index, you can use this function (credit: [codeproject Article: Read and Write Microsoft Excel with Open XML SDK](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/670141/Read-and-Write-Microsoft-Excel-with-Open-XML-SDK)):

```
dim regexColName = New Regex("[A-Za-z]+", RegexOptions.Compiled)

Private Function ConvertCellReferenceToNumber(cellReference As String) As Integer
    Dim colLetters = regexColName.Match(cellReference).Value.ToCharArray()
    Array.Reverse(colLetters)

    Dim convertedValue = Asc(colLetters(0)) - 65

    For i = 1 To colLetters.Length - 1
        Dim current = Asc(colLetters(i)) - 64
        convertedValue += current * Math.Pow(26, i)
    Next

    Return convertedValue
End Function
```

with this function you can simulate empty cells:

```
Dim row As Row = SheetData.Descendants(Of Row)().FirstOrDefault(Function(y) y.RowIndex.Value = 2)

Dim cells = row.Descendants(Of Cell).ToDictionary(
    Function(cell) ConvertCellReferenceToNumber(cell.CellReference),
    function(cell) cell)

For i = 0 To cells.Keys.Max()
    Dim c As Cell
    If (cells.TryGetValue(i, c)) Then
        Console.WriteLine(c.CellValue) 'need hanle for special values 
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("empty")
    End If
Next
```